# AVCaptureDevice.setExposureTargetBias() doesn't affect exposure as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation, autoexposurecompensation

The documentation isn't very clear on this, but it kind of implies that the value you send into this function would be measured in stops. But the results are not as expected, especially in bright scenes. The exposure does not increase by the same number of stops as the value I send to setExposureTargetBias(). The larger the number the bigger the discrepancy. I am calculating exposure using the following

```
 let shutter = Float(avCaptureDevice.exposureDuration.value)/Float(avCaptureDevice.exposureDuration.timescale)
 let aperture = avCaptureDevice.lensAperture
 let iso = avCaptureDevice.iso
 let exposure = log2f(aperture*aperture/(shutter*iso/100))
```

In theory if exposure increases by one stop the value of the variable exposure would increase by 1. This is not what I am seeing when I increase exposure bias by 1 though